Threejs shader updating normals
I have a glb animation of a scroll unrolling. It‘s a point level animation that exported from Cinema4D with morph targets.
If I set the flatshading to true, it is perfect except of course the faceted look that goes with flat shading.
Updating the vertex normals does not work. It just displays the normals from the exported animation in its first state, when the scroll is rolled, not unfolded.
How can I make the smooth shader behave like the flat shader in calculating the normals at each animation frame but with smooth shading?
Updating vertex normals does not work due to morph targets. Asking chatgpt to write custom shader resulted only in errors. Only flatshading:true works fine, but I don‘t like the faceted look.
